# CouchDB error in Hyperledger Fabric network - database does not exist

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

I have a very simple test-network for Hyperledger Fabric. Network start as normal through Docker Compose and connection between peers and orderer is fine. Each peer has a separate container as their database, with CouchDB.

System: Ubuntu 18.04

The issue arrise when a peer try to interact with its CouchDB container, then an error message occurs and the peer node exits.

Here is the container log from CouchDB:

**This is the error I receive in the couchdb container logs:**

[info] 2019-11-26T10:28:38.398968Z nonode@nohost <0.195.0> -------- Apache CouchDB has started on http://any:5986/

[info] 2019-11-26T10:28:38.399538Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch started on node nonode@nohost

[info] 2019-11-26T10:28:38.399838Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application ets_lru started on node nonode@nohost

[info] 2019-11-26T10:28:38.428548Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application rexi started on node nonode@nohost

[info] 2019-11-26T10:28:38.441617Z nonode@nohost <0.201.0> -------- open_result error {not_found,no_db_file} for _nodes

[warning] 2019-11-26T10:28:38.441655Z nonode@nohost <0.271.0> -------- creating missing database: _nodes

[info] 2019-11-26T10:28:38.470566Z nonode@nohost <0.201.0> -------- open_result error {not_found,no_db_file} for _dbs

[warning] 2019-11-26T10:28:38.470600Z nonode@nohost <0.285.0> -------- creating missing database: _dbs

[warning] 2019-11-26T10:28:38.470639Z nonode@nohost <0.284.0> -------- creating missing database: _dbs

[info] 2019-11-26T10:28:38.478597Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application mem3 started on node nonode@nohost

[info] 2019-11-26T10:28:38.478957Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application fabric started on node nonode@nohost

[info] 2019-11-26T10:28:38.529437Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application chttpd started on node nonode@nohost

[notice] 2019-11-26T10:28:38.553132Z nonode@nohost <0.322.0> -------- chttpd_auth_cache changes listener died database_does_not_exist at mem3_shards:load_shards_from_db/6(line:395) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/1(line:370) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/2(line:399) <= mem3_shards:for_docid/3(line:86) <= fabric_doc_open:go/3(line:38) <= chttpd_auth_cache:ensure_auth_ddoc_exists/2(line:187) <= chttpd_auth_cache:listen_for_changes/1(line:134)

[error] 2019-11-26T10:28:38.555361Z nonode@nohost emulator -------- Error in process <0.323.0> with exit value:

{database_does_not_exist,[{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_db,"_users",[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,395}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,1,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,370}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,399}]},{mem3_shards,for_docid,3,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,86}]},{fabric_doc_open,go,3,[{file,"src/fabric_doc_open.erl"},{line,38}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,ensure_auth_ddoc_exists,2,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,187}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,listen_for_changes,1,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,134}]}]}

**Here is the error log from the peer container trying to reach the CouchDB:**

2019-11-26 10:29:00.236 UTC [ledgermgmt] CreateLedger -> INFO 021 Creating ledger [allarewelcome] with genesis block

2019-11-26 10:29:00.238 UTC [fsblkstorage] newBlockfileMgr -> INFO 022 Getting block information from block storage

panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x28 pc=0xcecbb6]

Comment: Your database has not been properly configured yet. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/55602347/13860

Comment: `docker-compose.yaml` files for the CouchDB and the peer would help to analyze the error. Not difficult to make both work together, so it is caused by some missconfiguration in the environment variables defined in `docker-compose.yaml` by sure.

Comment: @kekomal please see additional information below - as I have not yet managed to resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I checked both compose-yaml and the env variables in container itself, seems all fine. Also the couchDB is running as expected. Here is additional information, as I am very unsure about what the issue migth be.

```
**core.yml:**

    ledger:

      blockchain:

      state:
         stateDatabase - options are "goleveldb", "CouchDB"
         goleveldb - default state database stored in goleveldb.
         CouchDB - store state database in CouchDB
        stateDatabase: CouchDB
         Limit on the number of records to return per query
        totalQueryLimit: 100000
        couchDBConfig:

           couchDBAddress: 127.0.0.1:5984

           username:

           password:

           maxRetries: 3

           maxRetriesOnStartup: 12

           requestTimeout: 35s

           internalQueryLimit: 1000

           maxBatchUpdateSize: 1000

           warmIndexesAfterNBlocks: 1

           createGlobalChangesDB: false

    **docker-compose.yml:**

    peer0.org1.example.com:
        container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
        image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
        environment:
          - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
          - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
          - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
          - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
          - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
          - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
          - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
          - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=startFiles_basic
          - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
          - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdbOrg1Peer0:5984
          - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=peer0.Org1
          - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=password
        working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
        command: peer node start
        # command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
        ports:
          - 7051:7051
          - 7053:7053
        volumes:
          - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
          - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
          - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
          - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        depends_on:
          - orderer.example.com
          - couchdbOrg1Peer0
        networks:
          - basic

      couchdbOrg1Peer0:
        container_name: couchdbOrg1Peer0
        image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
        environment:
          - COUCHDB_USER=​peer0.Org1
          - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=​password
        ports:
          - "5984:5984"
        networks:
          - basic


    **From the CLI logs**

    user:~/Desktop/fabric-samples$ curl http://127.0.0.1:5984/
    {"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"2.2.0","git_sha":"2a16ec4","features":["pluggable-storage-engines","scheduler"],"vendor":{"name":"The Apache Software Foundation"}}

    user:docker exec -it peer0.org1.example.com bashroot@ba0c7f2796b6:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric# printenv
    CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdbOrg1Peer0:5984
    CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
    CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
    CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
    CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=password
    FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
    PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
    PWD=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
    CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=startFiles_basic
    CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
    SHLVL=1
    HOME=/root
    FABRIC_CFG_PATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric
    CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=peer0.Org1
    CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
    CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
    _=/usr/bin/printenv
```